# modifying zxing library files barcode scanner iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to modify the zxing library files (which is an open source library) a bit to have the cameraFlashMode On as soon as user taps on scan button to open the bar code scanner camera. Also, I want to add one or two UIButtons at the bottom. In short, I want to customize that camera view according to my needs.
If anyone has done it or knows how to do it, then please help me.

Comment: Someone please provide me an answer. I need it urgently. Will I have to use AVDeviceCapture for accessing camera because in zxing library, I am unable to find UIImagePickerViewController for camera.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your customizations in OverlayView.m. Add the buttons in

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)theFrame cancelEnabled:(BOOL)isCancelEnabled oneDMode:(BOOL)isOneDModeEnabled;
```

And set the flashmode in ZXingWidgetController.h in

```
- (void)initCapture;
```

Set the flashMode on with:

```
- (void)activateFlash {
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {

        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if ( [device hasFlash] ) {
            [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```